# referencing a module type signature

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to reference a type in a module signature to build another type.

```
module type Cipher = sig

  type local_t
  type remote_t

  val local_create : unit -> local_t
  val local_sign : local_t -> Cstruct.t -> Cstruct.t
  val remote_create : Cstruct.t -> remote_t
  val remote_validate : remote_t -> Cstruct.t -> bool

end

module Make_cipher :                                                              
  functor (Cipher_impl : Cipher) ->
    sig                                                                         
      type local_t = Cipher_impl.local_t                                        
      type remote_t = Cipher_impl.remote_t
      val local_create : unit -> local_t
      val local_sign : local_t -> Cstruct.t -> Cstruct.t
      val remote_create : Cstruct.t -> remote_t
      val remote_validate : remote_t -> Cstruct.t -> bool
    end

type self_t = 
  {
    mutable modules : (module Cipher) list;
    mutable locals : Cipher.local_t list;
  }
```

When I compile this, I get 'Error: Unbound module Cipher' for self_t. I'm not too sure what to do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you should use `Cipher_impl.local_t` instead of `Cipher.local_t`

A module type (aka signature) is just a specification of module interface. When you need a type, you need to refer to a particular type in a particular module, not in the signature.

Comment: Ah - but there are many `Cipher_impl.local_t` implementations. Perhaps I need to somehow make this polymorphic?

Comment: The `Cipher_impl` is a functor parameter that stands for many implementations. Its like a formal parameter of a function, that stands for many possible values

Comment: If I do a `mutable locals : Cipher_impl.local_t list;` then I get `Error: Unbound module Cipher_impl`

Comment: You need to do this inside the functor implementation, i.e., `module Make_cipher (C : Cipher) = struct type self_t = { mutable locals : C.local_t } end`

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work outside of the functor - I create different cipher algorithm modules, and for each module I generate a local key (local_t). I then hold these keys in a list, which I can then iterate over.

Comment: then you're completely misunderstanding functors. I would suggest to delete this question and try to create a new one, where you describe what you want to do, so we can try to help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of functors and helping me out. I managed to find a solution to creating local_t types which weren't contained in the functor - `type local_key = LK : 'a * (module Cipher with type local_t = 'a) -> local_key`.  Thanks again for the help. Cheers, Nick